# polkit failed to start Authorization Manager (Debian Trixie)

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

On Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid, xfce4 4.18

I get :
**polkit.service failed to start.**

```
$ systemctl status polkit.service
aug 09 23:48:43 test-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start Authorization Manager
```

Running **polkitd** directly with cli, gives me:

```
[system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1': timed out
```

update :

```
# /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd
Successfully changed to user polkitd
10:52:58.782: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
10:52:58.783: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
10:52:58.787: Finished loading, compiling and executing 6 rules
Entering main event loop
Connected to the system bus
10:52:58.788: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system    bus


journalctl :

systemd[1721]: Starting XFCE notifications service...
systemd[1]: polkit.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=31/SYS
systemd[1]: polkit.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Authorization Manager.
dbus-daemon[1881]: [session uid=1000 pid=1881] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
systemd[1721]: Started XFCE notifications service.
```

no return !

Comment: The update has you running the daemon and not getting a return/exit. That should be the normal operation, this is a service which would ideally be started by an init system (systemd in this case) on the background to run indefinitely. Could you post journald output for when it fails to start?